# What is the Dirichlet Proces Mixture Models posterior

Tags: posterior, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

I am trying to understand Dirichlet Process Mixture models. One of the videos I have been watching is by [Tamara Broderick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mC-jZcEb7ME&t=1306s). I think it is a very good introductory video to Dirichlet Process mixture models. Another resource I am looking at is by [radford Neal](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/npbayes/papers/neal_sampling.pdf) which talks about MCMC sampling for the posterior distribution of Dirichlet Porcess Mixture Models. Both videos also talk about sampling from the posterior distribution of a DP mixture, however I am not sure why the posterior distributions Neal and Tamara refers to are different.

In particular, [Tamara Broderick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mC-jZcEb7ME&t=1306s) does not talk about updating the cluster parameters $\mu_k$
but rather only the cluster assignments $z_i$. [radford Neal](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/npbayes/papers/neal_sampling.pdf) on the other hand talks about sampling a new cluster mean $\mu_k$ from the posterior at every step of gibbs sampling. (Algorithm 2)

I have a few questions regarding.

1. What is the posterior distribution of a DP mixture model ?
2. What is the difference between [Tamara Broderick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mC-jZcEb7ME&t=1306s) and [radford Neal](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/npbayes/papers/neal_sampling.pdf) method ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, Tamera Broderick addresses the case when the cluster parameters can be analytically marginalized (she mentions this briefly at https://youtu.be/mC-jZcEb7ME?t=1042) whereas Radford Neal's paper is about methods that explicitly sample the cluster parameters.

Comment: Might you know what the full posterior distribution for the Dirichlet process mixture model is with respect to eq (2.3) of radford neal's paper ?